# How to define xpath of button in this case (selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image]

Hi maybe someone helps me, in this case, I need to define XPath of button on this page by selenium and I have a problem ?

```
span Zaloguj
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use anyone from below xpath:

```
//span[text()='Zaloguj']
```

or

```
//div[@class ='btn btn-login']/span[text()='Zaloguj']
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use anyone from below xpath: .

```
//span[text()='Zaloguj']
```

And if you find many more then use

```
(//span[text()='Zaloguj'])[1]
```

You can give an index according to your best matches

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to be dependent on text, cause text may change, you can use the below XPath :

```
//i[@class='icon-login']//following-sibling::span
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Comment: You should leave a comment here. Do not post a new answer for instead do a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Though you are able to write xpath for the span tag using text, if you are not able to perform a click due to it's a Pseudo-element, use following code to perform click ..

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('icon-login')[0].click();");
```